# android:inputType="numberDecimal" vs. InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL

Tags: android, layout, attributes

The following condition evaluates to false. Isn't suppose to be true?

```
editText.getInputType() == InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL
```

specially when in the xml file, I have

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal"
```

Debugging shows that

```
editText.getInputType() = 8194
```

and

```
InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL = 8192
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

numberDecimal refers to both TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER and TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL.  So when you compare, you need to do this.

```
editText.getInputType() == (InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL | InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER)
```

Comment: I was searching madly for this solution. THANKS

Answer (score 4):

`andorid:inputType="numberDecimal"` And `InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL` both are same [numberDecimal](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/text/InputType.html) is for taking decimal inputs, so all the digits from **0 to 9 including the decimal point** `sign(.)`

Please read this for more information

- **[getInputType()](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getInputType())**